# How to automate job of flink sql with Oozie on HUE?

Tags: ssh, apache-flink, oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

I would like to automate the job of the Flink SQL client using Oozie on Hue.
I have a script called "start-job.sh" and a SQL script called "flink.sql". If I run the command "start-job.sh flink" in my shell, it executes the "flink.sql" script. Additionally, I'm using the MobaXterm shell to access the server.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to automate this job using Oozie. I have previously attempted an SSH connection, but it didn't work.